# Error in showing and hiding UIPickerview

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I'm new to the x-code word, and i need your help.

I'm trying to write a code to show and hide the UIpickerview.

the Uipickerview must show when i press the select button in the view controller,and hide when i press the done button in the toolbar and then show the selected data in a label

this is my code..

this is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *NumExamPicker;
    NSMutableArray *NumExamName;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbout;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *PickerContainer;
- (IBAction)SelectButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)DoneButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

and this is my .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize lbout;
@synthesize PickerContainer;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NumExamName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [NumExamName addObject:@"One"];
    [NumExamName addObject:@"Two"];
    [NumExamName addObject:@"Three"];
    [NumExamName addObject:@"Four"];

    PickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 600, 320, 206);
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NumExamName count];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    lbout.text = [NumExamName objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)SelectButton:(id)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    PickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 362, 320, 206);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (IBAction)DoneButton:(id)sender {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    PickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 600, 320, 206);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
@end
```

when i run the simulator, it crashes and stops at this method:

```
//  main.m
//  showandhideuipickerview

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I don't know how to solve it.

oh one more thing, I'm working with one single view, will it be the same if i want it not to be the fist view? or should i add more code.

thanks...

Comment: ave you defined `NumExamPicker` in InterfaceBuilder, i.e. is it already a view thats contained in PickerContainer?

Comment: @Flexicoder I have dragged and dropped the the uipickerview to the .h file.is that what you mean?...i placed the uipickerview in a view and named it PickerContainer

Comment: So you've laid out the UI elements visually, and the dragged to the .h to create the properties? In your code the 3 places you have `PickerContainer.frame =` change this to `self.PickerContainer.frame =` does that fix it?

Comment: at which button it crashes? when done button pressed or when picker  row selected?

Comment: picker delegates are fine ???did you set them?

Comment: @Flexicoder yes i did that to create the properties

Comment: @Flexicoder no it did not

Comment: @QualityCoder when i run the simulator it crashes immediately

Comment: @QualityCoder i don't think so..how to set them?

Comment: http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/08/04/iphone-development-tutorial-add-a-uipickerview/ please see point 6

Comment: can you give the crash log so that I can help?

Comment: @QualityCoder it does not work...when i create a single view it does not have a xib file...and when i create one next to it appear (A) and the other files(M)...i think that is way it does not work?!

Comment: @QualityCoder  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/25qs5iylxtowp13/Wzvg7TrUBU this is the view that i'm working on

Answer (score 1):

Pls add this delegate method of UIPickerView

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow: (NSInteger)row forComponent: (NSInteger)component {
    return [NumExamName objectAtIndex:row];
}
```